# Nbclust throwing error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to run a dataframe of 9 columns and 1064 rows through a k-means clustering algorithm, but I get the following error:

`Error in NbClust(df, min.nc = 2, max.nc = 15, method = "kmeans") : 
  The TSS matrix is indefinite. There must be too many missing values. The index cannot be calculated.`

However, there are no missing values

```
> dim(df)
[1] 1064    9

> sum(is.na(df))
[1] 0
```

Any idea what the problem could be and how to resolve it?

```
> head(df)
  hr_830 hr_930 hr_1030 hr_1130 hr_160 hr_180 hr_190 hr_200 hr_0
1      2      2       2       2      2      2      2      2    2
2      2      2       2       2      2      2      2      2    3
3      2      2       2       2      2      2      2      2    3
4      2      2       2       2      2      2      2      2    2
5      2      2       2       2      2      2      2      2    2
6      2      2       2       2      2      2      2      2    4
```

here is a sample of the input:

```
  > dput(input)
structure(list(hr_830 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), hr_930 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), hr_1030 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), hr_1130 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), hr_160 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), hr_180 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), hr_190 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), hr_200 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), hr_0 = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
)), .Names = c("hr_830", "hr_930", "hr_1030", "hr_1130", "hr_160", 
"hr_180", "hr_190", "hr_200", "hr_0"), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have too many *constant* attributes, too.

Most (all?) of these methods assume *continuous* values, not integers.